# How to divide vector by double?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to normalize(scale values between 0 and 1 )vector of velocities.

```
normalized v(i)=v(i)-vmin/(vmax-vmin)
```

My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
vector<double> velocity;
vector<double> results;
double vLower, vUpper, v1;

ifstream inputFile1("/home/milenko/gust/vel.dat");

if (inputFile1) {        
    double value;

    while ( inputFile1 >> value ) {
        velocity.push_back(value);
    }
}

vLower = *min_element(velocity.begin(), velocity.end());
vUpper = *max_element(velocity.begin(), velocity.end());

v1 = vUpper-vLower;
transform(velocity.begin(), velocity.end(), velocity.begin(), [vLower](double i) -> double { return i - vLower; });
transform (velocity.begin(), velocity.end(), v1, results, divides<double>());
for (auto c : results) { std::cout << c << std::endl; }
}
```

The first transform is working fine,it subtracts minimum value from each vector element.The problem is with the second one,which should divide the velocity with v1.

```
 In instantiation of ‘_OIter std::transform(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _OIter, _BinaryOperation) [with _IIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >; _IIter2 = double; _OIter = std::vector<double>; _BinaryOperation = std::divides<double>]’:
v1.cpp:29:76:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4964:59: error: no match for ‘operator++’ (operand type is ‘std::vector<double>’)
       for (; __first1 != __last1; ++__first1, ++__first2, ++__result)
                                                           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4965:37: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)
  *__result = __binary_op(*__first1, *__first2);
                                     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4965:2: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::vector<double>’)
  *__result = __binary_op(*__first1, *__first2);
```

Any ideas how to solve this?Or is it possible with single transform?

Comment: [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) takes either 3 or 4 iterators and a functor, in the second call you give it 2 iterators a `double` and a container as the first 4 arguments...

Comment: @ I see now,well I should divide velocity by v1.How should the functor look like?

Comment: `normalized v(i)=v(i)-vmin/(vmax-vmin)` should be `normalized v(i)=(v(i)-vmin)/(vmax-vmin)` and divide is REALLY slow, you'd be much better off setting a value `double scale = 1/(vmax-vmin)` and then setting each `v(i)=(v(i)-vmin)*scale`

Comment: @RyanP Thanks,didn't thought about this.But yes the vector will be quite large so you are probably right!

Comment: `std::transform` is great for some things but in this case I'd be tempted to use one ranged-based for loop instead: `for(auto& v : velocity) v = (v-vmin)*scale;`

Comment: Floating point division is not that slow, integer division is much worse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`v1` should not be in `transform` call.

```
transform (velocity.begin(), velocity.end(), back_inserter(results), 
bind(divides<double>(), placeholders::_1, v1));
```

But since you use lambda in first transform it will be more simple to use lambda in second transform too.

```
transform (velocity.begin(), velocity.end(), back_inserter(results),
[&v1](double v) { return v / v1; });
```

Comment: For consistency it should be `std::divides` too

Comment: @Slava since there is `using namespace std`, all `std::` was removed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you could use standard algorithm `std::minmax_element` to find the minimum and the maximum traversing the vector only one time.

And secondly sometimes it is better to write a range-based for loop than to use an algorithm with a lambda expression because  in the first case the code will be more readable.

So you can write

```
auto minmax = std::minmax_element( velocity.begin(), velocity.end() );

auto x = *minmax.first / ( *minmax.second - *mimax.first );

for ( auto &value : velocity ) value -= x;
```

If you need to create a new vector then you can write insted

```
auto minmax = std::minmax_element( velocity.begin(), velocity.end() );

auto x = *minmax.first / ( *minmax.second - *mimax.first );

vector<double> results;
resultr.reserve( velocity.size() );

for ( auto value : velocity ) results.push_back( value - x );
```

Comment: I think we are assuming `v(i)=v(i)-vmin/(vmax-vmin)` was a typo and OP meant `v(i)=(v(i)-vmin)/(vmax-vmin)`.

Comment: @Chris Drew In the context of the question in fact it is unimportant what expression to use.:)